# Eigenvalues of this Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am looking for the analytic solution for the eigenvalues of a $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix of the form
$$
A_n=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & z & z^2 & z^3 & \cdots & z^n \\
z & 1 & z & z^2 & \cdots & z^{n-1} \\
\vdots & & \vdots & & & \vdots \\
z^n & z^{n-1} & \cdots & & z & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $z$ is complex with unity modulus. The eigenvalues $\lambda$ obey the function $\det(A_n-\lambda I_{n+1})=0$ that gives
\begin{align}
\det(A_n-\lambda I_{n+1})=\det\begin{pmatrix}A_{n-1}-\lambda I_{n} & v_n \\ v^T_{n} & 1-\lambda\end{pmatrix}=(1-\lambda-v^T_n(A_{n-1}-\lambda I_n)^{-1}v_n)\det(A_{n-1}-\lambda I_n),
\end{align}
where $v_n=(z^n,z^{n-1},\cdots,z^2,z)^T$. $v^T_n(A_{n-1}-\lambda I_n)^{-1}v_n$ can be calculated as
\begin{align}
v^T_n(A_{n-1}-\lambda I_n)^{-1}v_n &= (z(A_{n-1}-\lambda I_n)e_n+z\lambda e_n)^T(A_{n-1}-\lambda I_n)^{-1}(z(A_{n-1}-\lambda I_n)e_n+z\lambda e_n)\\
&=z^2(1+\lambda)+z^2\lambda^2e^T_n(A_{n-1}-\lambda I_n)^{-1}e_n \\
&=z^2(1+\lambda)+z^2\lambda^2\frac{\det(A_{n-2}-\lambda I_{n-1})}{\det(A_{n-1}-\lambda I_n)}.
\end{align}
Substituting into the second equation, I get a recursion relation
$$
\det(A_n-\lambda I_{n+1})=(1-\lambda-z^2(1+\lambda))\det(A_{n-1}-\lambda I_n)-z^2\lambda^2\det(A_{n-2}-\lambda I_{n-1}).
$$
Then the general form of $\det(A_n)$ is
$$
\det(A_n-\lambda I_{n+1})=c_1a^n_1+c_2a^n_2\ \  {\rm with}\ \ a_{1,2}=\frac{z^2(1+\lambda)+\lambda-1\pm\sqrt{(z^2(1+\lambda)+\lambda-1)^2-4z^2\lambda^2}}{-2z^2\lambda^2}
$$
and $c_{1,2}$ determined by the boundary condition $\det(A_{1,2})$. The eigenvalues $\lambda$ is the solution of
$$
c_1a^n+c_2a^n_2=0,
$$
which is impossible to solve for large $n$. The recursion method I used above seems very inefficient for this problem. Is there any other method to solve this problem?